# Can anyone help me to prove $(Y- \overline{Y})'(Y- \overline{Y})=Y'Y - n\overline{Y}^2$?

Tags: statistics

I want to prove that $(Y - \overline{Y})'(Y - \overline{Y})=Y'Y - n\overline{Y}^2$.

The only thing that I have done is to say that $$(Y - \overline{Y})'(Y - \overline{Y})=Y'Y-Y'\overline{Y}-\overline{Y}'Y+\overline{Y}'\overline{Y}$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question. In addition, can you explain what is meant by $Y_i$, $\overline{Y}$, $'$, and $n$?

Comment: I have edited it. there is no Yi

Comment: Y,Y' are matrices and (Y - \overline{Y})'(Y - \overline{Y})=sum\limits^n_{i=1}(y_i-\overline{y})^2

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$
\begin{align}
& (Y - \overline{Y})'(Y - \overline{Y}) \\[8pt]
= {} & Y'Y - Y'\overline{Y} - \cancel{\overline{Y}'Y} + \cancel{\overline{Y}' \overline{Y}} \\[8pt]
= {} & Y'Y - Y'\overline Y.
\end{align}

Above, I take $\overline Y$ to mean a column vector in which every one of the $n$ components is equal to the mean of the $n$ components of $Y.$

Since you're using the notation $\overline Y$ to refer to that vector, let us use the notation $m(Y)$ to refer to the mean, which occurs $n$ times in the vector $\overline Y.$ Thus $m(Y) = (Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)/n$ where $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)'.$

Now observe that
\begin{align}
& Y'\overline Y = Y_1m(Y) + \cdots + Y_n m(Y) \\[8pt]
= {} & (Y_1+\cdots +Y_n)m(Y) = \big(nm(Y)\big) m(Y) \\[8pt]
= {} & = n\big(m(Y)\big)^2,
\end{align}
and this seems to be what you mean by $n\overline Y^2.$